# Parsing a SOAP response without wsdl using java/php

Tags: java, php, soap

I wish to consume a SOAP webservice from the Govt. of India public data sets. Here is an sample URL:
http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Fish_2013.xml

I have been using REST APIs and have never used a SOAP one.This is a SOAP webservice and it does not give me any information about the wsdl file location. As per my understanding I can generate a client using the WSDL if available and use it but how do I use a SOAP API without WSDL.
Most of the other posts talk about changing the response format but then its not possible in my case.

Comment: you need WSDL for this. What is the SOAP service address?

Comment: I have posted the link. This is all that they have provided on their site

Comment: @Amol Do you want data out of this xml?

Comment: you can access that XML without SOAP request, just simple HTTP get. Then why you want use SOAP for this? Just parse it as simple xml file.

Comment: This does not seem like a SOAP service. It's looks like a static xml file to me.

Comment: that makes sense...although they update this file everyday it seems....writing a simple xml parser would be a long task...is there any method by which I can do unmarshelling easily ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 tricks:

- install a local webserver
- map the localhost/yourproject?wsdl to that xml file
- use a Soap client generator tool on that wsdl link ( some allow other links wich doesn't end at wsdl some doesn't)
- use the generated artifacts to consume soap.